# Testing a website for mobile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, media-queries

I got a ASP.NET MVC website that is working fine in most desktop browers, now I need to make a version for mobile and my though is to use CSS Media Queries for this but I have no clue on how to test the page during development? Is there any desktop application that can be used like a mobile browser?

Comment: have you seen http://iphone4simulator.com/ and http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-testing-your-site-on-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is test the media queries firing on certain viewport widths simply reduce the width of your browser.  You can watch the UI change as different media queries fire.

You can also use browser plugins to define and set viewport resolutions.  I use "Resize Window" for Chrome.

There is an Android emulator out there that you can download and run on the desktop, but this is mostly used for testing device specific features.

When it comes down to it the best way to test mobile websites is on the devices you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true)
    {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I do know about that, what I need is somekind of mobile browser emulator.

Answer (score 0):

To test your website you can use Chrome, there is a nice features included in it. You can change the user-agent and, then, emulate à resolution of an Ipad, Iphone or any smartphone.

It's pretty usefull to test responsive design and stuff :)

Well, in addition, be carefull it's only "simulation" it never remplace some real tests but it's nice for conception and pre-production process !

Here is a link about the change user agent feature of chrome : http://googlesystem.blogspot.fr/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 3 tools that can help you:

1. Adobe Shadow http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow: It lets you sync up the website you're viewing on your desktop browser to your mobile through the Adobe Shadow App, and you can use Chrome's dev tools on the mobile site through this method.
2. Remote Debugging with Chrome on Androids https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging: like Adobe Shadow you can debug and test your site through the chrome dev tools. However, you'll need an Android phone running on ICS.
3. Lastly, if you have the Xcode - you can use the iPhone simulator to view your sites. It is very accurate, you don't get the realtime debugging like you would with the previous two, but you can test your site on the fly after each update.